# Can HikariCp be useful if deploy application on major application servers?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, hikaricp

I am pretty sure WebLogic, Websphere, Jboss EAP and other J2EE application server provides their own service to optimize database connection pooling. At this point is there any benefit to still integrate a Spring application with HikariCp? May be HikariCp performs better (in question) but there will be unavoidable issues for configuration and compatibility.

Better question is: what are the benefits to use HikariCp in a Spring application if it will deploy on major commercial application servers other than Tomcat etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an opinion that `HikariCp` is the fastest connection pool in java world, [this graphics](https://brettwooldridge.github.io/HikariCP/) prove this fact. In this case criteria is statement Cycle in ops/ms. HikariCp is faster in two times than the closest rival. It's [a source code of this benchmarks](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP-benchmark), if i were you, i would launch them on own PC with specific to my environment. Last link saves your time, you have already written benchmarks (it's benefits of open source). HTH